# Facebook October 2013 breaking changes affect Feed and send

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

We are using **feed/post** api and send dialog box for our app in **Facebook**,
As **October 2013 breaking changes** are removing feed/post so, 
I am not able to post as it is declined by Facebook also we can not share post with multiple user as privacy is moved out, its more one-to-one communication. 
In send dialog the description field is removed so cann't send any pre-populated description in messages.

I am looking for a workaround as its hitting the major functionality of my app, as to share information between the users.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement has significance of the description, I think the best option could be the [Mention Tagging](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/tagging/#mentions).

The post will be published to the user's wall with the friends tagged in the post.

It's an Open Graph concept, if you are new to this you can start from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).

Else, you'll have to use [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)- FB.ui or [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/share-links/)- with user interaction. Depends on your requirement which one suits the best.

Comment: are we allowed to add our own custom description in Open Graph?
Can u give some kind of example, as they are showing the description loaded from a link and I don't have any link, I just have to show some informative message

Comment: Yes, the code is similar to `/me/feed`- just the OG experience and tags will be added. Go through the links